# Location Map of Android Devices

Tags: android, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a problem in hand as mentioned below:

We have set of N Android Devices. For each of these N device we have a distance vector to M Devices (M < N and M is a subset of N) device. Rest (N-M) devices are not accessible to each other. (Means only few devices know the distance vector of these devices)

Assuming the position of these devices do not change, is it possible to create a location map of relative positions of these devices?

Comment: Are the locations of these devices held in a centralized place? Why don't you use Google Maps and create a layout overlay using your devices' locations?

Comment: This is because, I have to consider the devices which are Indoor - Inside buildings

Comment: Could you elaborate the question! Are all the devices inside one building? How do the devices communicate to each other? Is all the data kept in a centralized location? Do you have a map of the building or area containing the devices?

Comment: Devices are not in same building..they will be connected through wi-fi-direct. there is no central data..devices will communicate to each other once connected..and map should contain the relative position of these devices.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that your devices broadcast their status to each other once connected. 
I see 3 ways you could create this location map:

1. You can use the [`LocationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to retrieve the device's latitude and longitude and then plot it on Google Maps.
2. You've said the devices' positions don't change, that means every time a device comes on, all the others that have its information will know where it's located. You could implement your own created map and just show the device on there every time it's active.
3. Also you could build the map by using a matrix and coordinates provided by the properties of each device. You said each device has a distance vector. Use this to generate the position of the device in the matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but apart from your 3rd option, other doesn't meet requirement. AS 1. we can't use google maps because devices can either inside the building or outside depending on the context. 2. We can assume that device location is fixed but where they will be can always change-e.g. they can be in playground, cafeteria or in buildings so we can't create our own map too. 3. Can you help me by letting me know how we can create the  map using a matrix and co-ordinates?????

Comment: pls help regarding your 3rd option, thats what we want but don't know how to implement.

Comment: Post the data structure of the device. What is that distance vector that you have?